# Error al crear una restricción usando una sentencia DDL en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Tengo que crear una restricción de clave primaria con identidad usando `DDL`:

```
ALTER TABLE LUGAR ADD CONSTRAINT PK_LUGAR PRIMARY KEY (IDLUGAR)
```

Pero me sale un error en la sentencia `IDENTITY`, ¿cómo puedo crear una restricción de clave primaria con identidad usando `DDL`?

El error que me muestra es el siguiente:

> Mens. 8111, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 2 Mensaje de error: No se puede definir una restricción PRIMARY KEY en una columna que admite valores NULL de la tabla 'LUGAR'. Mens. 1750, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 2 No se pudo crear la restricción. Consulte los errores anteriores.

Comment: Hola Gabriela, ¿nos puedes mostrar la estructura de tu tabla así como el error que te envía al ejecutar la sentencia? Esto nos ayudará a identificar más fácil el error y su corrección :)

Comment: Mens. 8111, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 2
Mensaje de error: No se puede definir una restricción PRIMARY KEY en una columna que admite valores NULL de la tabla 'LUGAR'.
Mens. 1750, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 2
No se pudo crear la restricción. Consulte los errores anteriores.

Comment: Lo ideal es que toda la información relacionada con la pregunta vaya directamente en el contenido de la pregunta. Por esta ocasión lo he hecho para que para futuros casos lo tomes en cuenta :) Mientras tanto, veamos como solucionar esa falla :)

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿ya tienes información en tu tabla, o está vacía?

Answer (score 3):

El error se debe a que no es posible crear una restricción a una columna que acepta valores nulos, es decir, la definición de la columna que será tu llave primaria primero debe ser `NOT NULL`. Suponiendo que `IDLUGAR` es de tipo de dato `INT`:

```
ALTER TABLE LUGAR ALTER COLUMN IDLUGAR INT NOT NULL
```

Luego, ya podrás crear la restricción como en un inicio lo requerías:

```
ALTER TABLE LUGAR ADD CONSTRAINT PK_LUGAR PRIMARY KEY (IDLUGAR)
```